# Need help creating animation on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, svg-animate

I'm not proficient in animation. I want to create some animation on scroll down.
So could someone suggest to me?

I tried is svg path, not ok.
What I want is when the visitor is scroll down, the images will be move on the curved, the invisible images will be also show and move, like circle.

Could someone suggest to me how can I create for this? and example?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ariel. We can help you with *your* code. Please add it to the question if you have it. A complex animation path like yours needs a combination of [CSS Motion Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Motion_Path) and [scroll events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event). Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Check (GSAP) Greensock animation
https://greensock.com/gsap/